PhantomWallet connector for RainbowKit does not work on mobile
I am using Wagmi with RainbowKit in my next.js app and want to use phantomWallet connector.
When I open my app on desktop Chrome, I am able to see the Phantom wallet option after downloading an extension to Chrome, but when I visit my website on mobile, I cannot see it on mobile iOS Chrome as an option after clicking on the @rainbow-me/rainbowkit Connect button. I tried download Phantom App and create an account there but did not help.
import { connectorsForWallets } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';
import {
  phantomWallet,
} from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/wallets';
import { createConfig, http, webSocket } from '@wagmi/core';

const connectors = connectorsForWallets(
  [
    {
      groupName: 'Recommended',
      wallets: [phantomWallet],
    },
  ],
  {
    appName,
    projectId,
  }
);

const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  connectors,
  ssr: false,
  chains: [
    arbitrumSepolia,
  ],
  transports: {
    [arbitrumSepolia.id]: fallback([
      http('https://sepolia-rollup.arbitrum.io/rpc'),
    ]),
  },
});


// for openning the modal am using:
import { ConnectButton } from '@rainbow-me/rainbowkit';

